# Remove language-keyboard combination on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout, language

I recently updated Windows `Feature update to Windows 10, version 1903`. It was right after the update that the unwanted change occurred. Now when I press `start` + `space` to change the keyboard/language I see the following three options.

[image]

I would like to get rid of the first one, i.e. i want to remove the option of having English language and Danish keyboard layout. How do I do that?

## What I have tried:

- I have looked in 'Settings' under 'Region & language', but don't see anything that can fix it, and it looks like there is just one keyboard for English language:
  [image]
- I have tried removing the Danish and English language pack, but it removes the wrong ones

Comment: Did you recently install a feature update?

Comment: Yes, recently updated to `Feature update to Windows 10, version 1903`. It was right after the update that the unwanted change occurred

Comment: I have seen issues caused y language packs, after a feature upgrade, that were solved by reinstalling those language packs.

Comment: Reinstalling all keyboards, within each language pack fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling all keyboards, within each language pack fixed the issue for me. It is done in the options for each

[image]