# Windows 10 showing keyboard input methods not listed in my preferences

Tags: windows, windows-10, language, input-languages

As the title says, I have only chosen these input methods for my keyboard:

[image: Listed preferences]

However, it also lists two additional input types I haven't chosen:

[image: Available inputs]

and it really messes with my Alt+Shift quick switching I need to do regularly. Is there a way to remove the last two from the list?

The problem appeared two days ago, I haven't changed any settings and can't recall if I allowed any Win10 updates in the meantime...

Edit: I also checked, the two languages in the preferences only have one keyboard inputs each, those being the two ones I really need.

Comment: You need to determine if you have installed any updates.  Check your Windows Update history to determine that fact and edit your question to include that very vital and relevant information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1488697/remove-language-keyboard-combination-on-windows-10) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1110939/why-after-removal-keyboard-it-reappears-after-some-time-windows-10/1295834#1295834)

Comment: This [duplicate](https://superuser.com/questions/1360623/cant-remove-unneeded-keyboard-layouts-no-such-setting-anywhere/1469157#1469157) is seriously a duplicate instead of the other duplicate questions but those other duplicates are still potential duplicate candidates

Comment: An answer already exists to this question.  There is no reason for me to submit an answer to this question, when it's already answered, by an existing answer to a different question.  Since I don't even know, what actually worked exactly, I couldn't submit that answer if I wanted to.